# Can i make Prettify work on any code block? without the class prettyprint?

Tags: javascript

i am using [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify), i am wondering if i can make it work with any `code` block, not requiring the `prettyprint` class.

else, how can i attach the class `prettyprint` dynamically, maybe using jquery. what i want to acheive is similar to stack overflow where code typed in the editor will be "pretty printed" in the preview and output.

i tried

```
$("#main").delegate("code", "ready", function() {
    // this does not seem to run at all?
    // intending to add the prettyprint class here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('code').addClass('prettyprint'); });
```

- `$(document).ready(<func>)` runs `<func>` when the DOM is ready.
- `$('code')` selects all code tags.
- `.addClass()` adds the specified class to any elements it is passed (in this case, all of the `code` tags).

Comment: but in my case i think i need to use delegate so that as user adds code into the textarea, in the markdown preview the code will be prettified. how can i do that. my code above dont seem to work. if i change the event to hover it works tho ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `delegate()` is necessary here. You just need to execute `prettyPrint()` every now and then to evaluate your preview. One solution might be to use `setInterval` to apply Prettify after every x seconds. Here's a quick example:

```
$('textarea').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    val = this.value.replace(/<code>/gi, '<code class="prettyprint">');
    $('#preview').html(val);
});
setInterval(function(){ prettyPrint(); }, 10000);
```

This would execute `prettyPrint()` every 10 seconds. It's not what I'd call perfect, but I think it does what you want. You'd probably also want to clear the interval if the user hasn't typed anything for a certain amount of time, but I hope this is enough to get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, this will work. But I am just very curious why my code doesn't even run? Shouldn't it run everytime a `<code>` becomes `ready`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `ready` event is tied to the `document` object and fires when the DOM is ready, nothing else. The syntax of `.delegate('code', 'ready', handler)` looks similar to `.bind('ready', handler)`, of which the documentation says: "This behaves similarly to the ready method but with one exception: If the ready event has already fired and you try to `.bind("ready")` the bound handler will not be executed." If you're determined to use `.delegate()` you may have to create a custom event. http://api.jquery.com/ready/